# OpenCV convert one color in to any other

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, colors

SSorry for my bad english . I have an image that Show 3 circles of different color, one red, one green and one blue and I can display this image into the 3 channels, but they appear white and in the code I display an image call "copy R" and I dont know how to make this copy R into another image whit any color I want to overlap the original image and changing the red color. How can i do this ???

this is my code, sorry is the first time i make a question and dont know how to publish properly

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#define w 400

using namespace cv;
```

/// Function headers

```
void MyFilledCircle(Mat img, Point center);
void MyFilledCircle1(Mat img, Point center);
void MyFilledCircle2(Mat img, Point center);
int main(void) {

//![create_images]

char window[] = "Original";

/// Create black empty images
Mat image = Mat::zeros(w, w, CV_8UC3);


/// 1.b. Creating circles
MyFilledCircle(image, Point(200, 200));
MyFilledCircle1(image, Point(150, 150));
MyFilledCircle2(image, Point(250, 250));


Mat channel[3];
split(image, channel);

//channel[0] = Mat::zeros(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);

merge(channel, 3, image);

Mat imageHSV;
Mat copy;


imshow(window, image);
//imshow("Color 1", imageHSV);

inRange(image, Scalar(0, 0, 255), Scalar(0, 0, 255), copy);
imshow("copy R", copy);


imshow("B", channel[0]);
imshow("G", channel[1]);
imshow("R", channel[2]);





//imshow("0", canal0);

//imwrite("dest.jpg", image);




waitKey(0);
return(0);
}

/// Function Declaration




//![myfilledcircle]

void MyFilledCircle1(Mat img, Point center)
{
circle(img,
    center,
    50,
    Scalar(0, 255, 0),
    FILLED,
    LINE_8);
}

void MyFilledCircle(Mat img, Point center)
{
circle(img,
    center,
    50,
    Scalar(0, 0, 255),
    FILLED,
    LINE_8);
}


void MyFilledCircle2(Mat img, Point center)
{
circle(img,
    center,
    50,
    Scalar(255, 0, 0),
    FILLED,
    LINE_8);
}
```

Comment: Change the numbers inside the `Scalar` types and you will get different colors.

Comment: if you mean to change the value of the scalar in te inrange operation, I already tried it and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it looks like `copy` is a binary mask, and you want to superimpose this mask on image, such that only the non-zero pixels in the mask retain their original color.

If my assumption is correct, then using the subtract method, as shown below, should help you out:

```
    Mat result;
    cvtColor(copy,copy,CV_GRAY2BGR);//change copy to a 3 channel image
    absdiff(image,image,result);//initialize mask as a black image of img.size()
    subtract(copy,image,result);
    subtract(copy,result,result);
```